# Casting Using a Variable of Type 'Type' Instead of Type Name

Tags: c#, reflection, casting

First I should mention it seems like this will be a duplicate, but I can't seem to find the question pertaining to this specific problem.  I only found close ones that don't address this specific approach and are thus not useful.

Consider this scenario where I'd like to cast something to a type.  I might do something like one of these:

```
var foo = GetInstanceOfSomeUnknownType();
var cast1 = (MyCustomType)foo;
var cast2 = foo as MyCustomType;
```

Not let's consider what to do if, for whatever reason, we can't directly cast using the name MyCustomType.  The below doesn't work:

```
var foo = GetInstanceOfSomeUnknownType();
var bar = "Whatever.";
Type someType = foo.GetType();
var cast1 = (someType)bar;
var cast2 = bar as someType;
```

In essence, you can do these sorts of casts using the type name, but not with a Type variable representing that type.  I'd like to cast something using a Type object of the type I want to cast to instead of its name.  Is there a way around this?

Comment: The type of `MyCustomType` is known at compile time. The type represented by the return value from `x.GetType()` is known at compile time *only* in cases where you could use `(MyCustomType)y)` instead.

Comment: No, you can't do a cast like that because the cast cannot be checked at compile time.

Comment: Assuming I'm prepared to handle runtime errors if the cast doesn't work, is there any way at all to cast to a type via a Type object?

Comment: @bubbleking, no, again, because casting is checked at compile time.  A type variable is only known at runtime.

Comment: Convert.ChangeType(SomeObject, SomeTypeVariable);

Comment: @tim casting and conversion are different things, and that method will throw an exception if the conversion type doesn't implement `IConvertible` or isn't one of ~16 types in the BCL.

Comment: While you are *technically* correct, there is no way (aside from late binding or dynamics) to cast at runtime. So if you want to change types at runtime you generally use the Convert functions.

Comment: @Tim So then is using the dynamic keyword something that could help here?

Comment: Is the type completely unknown, or can it only be a few known types? What is your code going to look like *after* it casts (pretend you *could* cast it to a unknown type)? If you do the same thing to the object regardless of the type, then you can probably just do this instead: `dynamic foo = GetInstanceOfSomeUnknownType();`, followed by, `foo.SomeMethodThatAlwaysExistsNoMatterTheType()`. If you are `switch`ing through method calls depending on the type, then just cast it right there because you know the type. I.e., `if (foo.GetType() == typeof(KnownType) { ((KnownType)foo).SomeMethod()) }`.

Comment: @Quantic - It was mostly an academic problem of curiosity.  What made me think of it was something I encountered while trying to make an Exception handler more flexible.  It was easy to take a different approach but it made me curious if there was a way to cast using a Type object.

Comment: You can use dynamics to interact with the object as a particular type without the compiler knowing it, or to remove restrictions that the compiler would put on you. You can't use it to truly cast, since using dynamics actually makes a different type all together. Ultimately the problem boils down to two questions. 1. Is the object already of the type you are trying to cast it to (That is, is the underlying type correct it is just boxed or not typed correctly locally) and 2. Is the type you are trying to cast it to a restricted set, or could it be any type.